# Convert RFC 3339 timestamp (R language)

Tags: r

I have a data frame with RFC 3339 format ("2012-04-12T19:02:32Z") and I need to turn into a date type R, I found as.POSIXct function but can not use it properly.

Comment: If `x` is your date - try `as.POSIXct(x,format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",tz="UTC")` see - `?strptime` for all the details of the date specifiers.

Comment: Beat me by a minute. Post it as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
R> as.POSIXct("2012-04-12T19:02:32Z", format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
[1] "2012-04-12 19:02:32 CDT"
R>
```

The arguments for the format string are detailed in the help page.

Comment: I think the `Z` at the end signifies `UTC` - if so it probably should be forced to that `tz`.

Comment: what's the difference between BRT and UTK?
And Thanks a lot for the help =D

Comment: @user2905427 - I have no idea. This is the first I've heard of BRT and UTK?

Comment: No, but I do not know what the best to use with R language, I will use graphs with Igraphs, any suggest?